# Why is it crazy expensive for a person to have their DHF backed up?

Tags: plot-explanation, altered-carbon

In S01E01 of *Altered Carbon* when Takeshi first speaks with Bancroft, it's explained that a full copy/backup of a person's DHF (stack) is extremely expensive; only for the super rich.

> BANCROFT: Have you ever heard of full-spectrum DHF remote storage backup?
>   TAKESHI: Yeah. Just never met anyone filthy rich enough to afford it.

In such a futuristic setting where medical and technological feats are seemingly easy to accomplish, what's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: That's never going to have an answer....it's basic economics, more complicated means more expensive.

Comment: @Paulie_D Just came across some discussion about it here: https://www.reddit.com/r/alteredcarbon/comments/81y3yn/why_most_of_the_people_didnt_back_up_their_stacks/

Comment: @Charles Didn't vote to close, but I think if you can, just make the question more clear/detailed

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Altered Carbon Wiki](https://netflixsalteredcarbon.fandom.com/wiki/Basic_Terms_and_Concepts):

> The Protectorate has made it prohibitively expensive to be backed up.  The very wealthy -- Meths ­­-- can afford satellite backups that preserve their last version of “self,” in the event that their stack should be destroyed.

Also consider:

- the DHF is backed up using a satellite link to a remote location - that has to have a high cost
- they keep a storage facility with multiple clones of their sleeve - that also is not cheap
- you can see less wealthy people struggling to have a dead relative re-sleeved in their birth sleeve, it's usually a random sleeve, a cheaper option.

Comment: Dead relatives cannot be be brought back in their birth sleeve. If the birth sleeve were still around, they wouldn't have been dead.